# How can I insert a picture into an Excel spreadsheet with Spreadsheet Light from a link rather than an image file?

Tags: c#, excel, spreadsheetlight

It's easy to add a picture to a sheet with Spreadsheet Light like this:

```
SLPicture logoPic = new SLPicture(@"C:\Platypus\DuckbillsUnlimited.png");
logoPic.SetPosition(0, 13);
sl.InsertPicture(logoPic);
```

...but I want to use an image at an URL, not from a file. How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using the image URL directly in the constructor of SLPicture, however that is not supported. You can use a workaround as follows:

1. Download the image file to a temporary location.
2. Use the downloaded file from the temporary location.

Modification to your sample code can be shown as follows:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), @"C:\Platypus\DuckbillsUnlimited.png");

SLPicture pic = new SLPicture(@"C:\Platypus\DuckbillsUnlimited.png");
logoPic.SetPosition(0, 13);
sl.InsertPicture(logoPic);
```

Not sure if there are other approaches but this definitely works!! Open for other suggestions!